Restlet Framework Native Image - Error 405 When Accessing Resource
I am currently working on a project using the Restlet framework and GraalVM's native image. I have successfully built a native image using Maven with the command mvn clean package -Pnative-image. The server starts up without any issues, but when I try to access the "/hello" resource with an HTTP client, I receive a 405 error, despite a JUnit test for the resource passed.
Here is a simplified version of my Main.java:
// ... imports ...

public class Main extends Application{

    private static final int HTTP_PORT = 8080;

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
        Component component = new Component();
        component.getServers().add(Protocol.HTTP, HTTP_PORT);
        component.getDefaultHost().attach("", new Main());
        component.start();
    }

    @Override
    public Restlet createInboundRoot() {
        Router router = new Router(getContext());
        router.attach("/hello", HelloWorldResource.class);
        return router;
    }
}

And my HelloWorldResource.java:
// ... imports ... 

public class HelloWorldResource extends ServerResource {
    private String name;

    @Override
    protected void doInit() throws ResourceException {
        this.name = getQueryValue("name");
        if (this.name == null) {
            this.name = "world";  
        }
    }

    @Get
    public String sayHello() {
        return "hello, " + this.name;
    }
}

Here are the relevant snippets from the pom.xml file that pertain to the issue:

The native-image-maven-plugin configuration:

<buildArgs>
    <!-- Fail when can't build successfully -->
    <buildArg>--no-fallback</buildArg>
    <!-- Max heap limit -->
    <buildArg>-J-Xmx16g</buildArg>
    <!-- Include all resources -->
    <buildArg>-H:IncludeResources=.*\.*$</buildArg>
    <buildArg>-H:+AllowIncompleteClasspath</buildArg>
    <buildArg>-H:ReflectionConfigurationFiles=${project.build.directory}/classes/META-INF/native-image/reflect-config.json</buildArg>
</buildArgs>


Surefire plugin:

<!--
    Surefire Plugin: Configures the test runner for the build.
        Added to create the JSON configuration files automatically 
        on tests.
-->
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.20.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <argLine>
            -agentlib:native-image-agent=config-output-dir=target/classes/META-INF/native-image
        </argLine>
    </configuration>
</plugin>

I suspect that something might be missing or misconfigured, but I'm not sure what it could be. I would appreciate any insights or suggestions from those familiar with the Restlet framework.

Did you have any success fixing this? As founder of Restlet Framework, official support for GraalVM is something of interest for a future version.

Hi, @JeromeLouvel I have had no success yet in generating a native image, the problem may be in the underlying 'Simple' framework. I'm still working on it.
